# Distance from a point to a convex set

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, convex-geometry

Consider a sphere, which is obviously a convex set. Consider any point outside the sphere, and say I want to find the minimum distance to this set.

In this case I can intuitively see that the closest point will lie on the line between the centre of the sphere and the outside point. So it will be a convex combination of the centre C and the outside point K.
$$pC + (1-p)K$$

Is this true for a point and a convex set in any dimension? That the point in the set closest to the outside point will be a convex combination of the centre and the outside point? If so, how would I prove this?

Would it also be true for any distance measure?

Comment: How is the center of a general convex set to be defined?

Comment: The center of a convex set is a bit misleading and not well-defined. For example, take the upper half plane in 2D space, it is a convex set but it won’t have a center as such. But still distance can be defined by taking infimum of all possible distances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Umm.....  why would you ever think that?

[image]

[image]